# 100% unit test code coverage - how to achieve with 'defensive' coding?

Tags: android, unit-testing, code-coverage

How would you go about getting 100% code coverage with the code below?

```
- (void)methodA {
    mState = Active;
    // do something ...
    methodB();
}

- (void)methodB {
    if (mState != Active) return;
    // do something else ...
}
```

I can test the `do something` and `do something else` parts easily, the problem lies in the `if (mState != Active) return;` line of `methodB`.  Since `methodA` is always setting the state to `Active`, the early return will never be executed.

I have the early return code in place just in case `methodB` is called elsewhere in the future. The code does not make sense to execute if `mState` is not `Active`, so it's defensive coding more or less.

I can add comments to the method stating "this method assumes the state is Active" or something, but that doesn't enforce the contract that the state must be active.  Throwing an exception and/or asserting could be possibilities here too, but again I'm not sure how I could test that to get 100% code coverage.

I totally understand that for cases like this it is probably irrelevant to get 100% code coverage - but unfortuantely the decision to get  is not mine (right now at least).  The 'bosses' want this done, and are being unreasonable about this if you ask me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: don't get too hung up on 100% coverage. You can spend a lot of time to reach that *number*, without adding more "quality" to your product!

Meaning: if that 100% goal is coming from an external driver, it might be worth to step back and discuss if a strict 100% goal really helps (I think it does not, but that is more of an opinion).

Assuming you want those 100% coverage, I see only see one option:
you enable your test to A) set `mState` to something else than `Active`  and B) to be able to call `methodB()` without going through method `methodA()`.

For example by having a setter for that field; and making `methodB()` at least package protected so that a unit test can invoke the method. But then you are making "test only" changes to your production code - just for the purpose of hitting that magic 100% number.

If `mState` is not a field, but would be returned by a getter, it *might* be possible to use a Mockito spy and partial mocking here.

Comment: Good points all around @GhostCat - I've pointed out the basic principles you talked about, and for the most part 'management' agrees.  It's a waste of time pursuing this any further, so for now this chapter can be closed.